# How to extract specific fields from google.protobuf (or just this converted to string)

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, data-processing, gtfs

I've got live data about trams and buses in my city from API, the type is:

```
print(type(feed.entity))
<class 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeContainer'>
```

It looks like this (converted to string looks the same):

```
[id: "4312"
vehicle {
  trip {
    trip_id: "\"1_740096^K"
    schedule_relationship: SCHEDULED
    route_id: "488"
  }
  position {
    latitude: 52.335411071777344
    longitude: 17.164840698242188
    speed: 14.4399995803833
  }
  current_stop_sequence: 2
  timestamp: 1654021682
  vehicle {
    id: "4312"
    label: "488/12"
  }
}
, id: "4318"
vehicle {
  trip {
    trip_id: "\"1_740217^G"
    schedule_relationship: SCHEDULED
    route_id: "432"
  }
  position {
    latitude: 52.39680862426758
    longitude: 16.94964027404785
    speed: 0.0
  }
  current_stop_sequence: 0
  current_status: INCOMING_AT
  timestamp: 1654021677
  vehicle {
    id: "4318"
    label: "432/8"
  }
}
,
```

My purpose is to get id, route_id, latitude and longitude of each vehicle (then use pandas and put this points into a map in folium). I'd like to know what's the best way to extract this either from an original format or a string.

Comment: you can probably iterate over it like a list, eg. `for entity in feed.entity` and then you can probably access those fields via dotted path through hierarchy of objects, eg. `entity.vehicle.trip.route_id`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the message to dictionary using `MessageToDict` from [protobuf](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/json_format.html), then access the fields that you want.